# D3 Pie chart tooltip and animation issue

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

Below is my code that initialises a pie chart. The problem I'm having is adding a tooltip and animation. I want to be able to hover over a slice on my pie chart and that slice should enlarge with a brief description (tooltip) of the data represented:

**Code:**

```js
<!-- contains the data that will be plotted on my pie chart -->
var data = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];

var radius = 500;


var color = d3.scale.ordinal(.range(['#00FFFF', '#32CD32', '#1E90FF', '#FF4500',
                             '#FFD700', '#FF7F50', '#DC143C', '#0000FF']);


    <!-- base container that will hold the pie chart. -->
    <!-- allows you to add function to the graph -->
    var container = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 1000)
      .attr("height", 1000)

    <!-- making proper adjustments to the container -->
    var group = container.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(500, 500)");


    <!-- arc is the base and shape of the pie chart-->
    <!-- it contains an inner.radius, outer.radius-->
    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(0)
      .outerRadius(radius - 100);



    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d;
      });


    <!-- grouping and binding my data to the pie chart -->
    var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(data)) <!-- passes data to pie layout-->
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    <!-- each color represents a number from the data-->
    <!-- creating a path  
    arcs
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data);
    });



    container.selectAll("slice")
    .data(pie(data))
    .enter()
    .attr("class", "slice")
    .attr("d", path)




    var slices = container.selectAll(".slice")
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter();

    slices
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return "slice" + color(d.data);
    })
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("mousemove", function(d) {
        var slicecolor = this;
        d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);

        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          d3.selectAll("path")
            .style({
              "opacity": 0.5
            });
        });
```

```css
.slice {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}
.slice:hover {
  fill: aliceblue;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
div.tooltip {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 50px;
  color: #549CFF;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  left: 80px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error

```
d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1); // <= errant semi-colon
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
            d3.selectAll("path")
                .style({"opacity":0.5});
        });
```